# Neo4J query to bring back user interests and other known users

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have an existing Neo4 query to bring back user interests and if any of those interests are related. The query is:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r1:INTERESTED_IN]-(i1:Interest)
WHERE u.emailAddress = 'bob@mail.com'
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r2:INTERESTED_IN]-(i2:Interest)
OPTIONAL MATCH (i1)-[r3:RELATED_TO]-(i2)
RETURN u, r1, i1, r2, i2, r3
```

This maps to a Spring Data Neo4J repository method as:

```
User findInterestsByEmailAddressIgnoreCase(@Param("emailAddress") String emailAddress);
```

I want to extend the graph so that users can know other users (e.g. bob knows fred and tom and fred and tom know each other too). How do I modify the same query to also bring back these relationships?

I tried adding an optional match for a user knowing another user as follows:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r1:INTERESTED_IN]-(i1:Interest)
WHERE u.emailAddress = 'bob@mail.com'
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r2:INTERESTED_IN]-(i2:Interest)
OPTIONAL MATCH (i1)-[r3:RELATED_TO]-(i2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u:User)-[r5:KNOWS]-(u2:User)
RETURN u, r1, i1, r2, i2, r3, r5, u2
```

This seems to run and bring back the graph in the neo4j browser but Spring Data seems to fail with the error

> org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException:
>   Incorrect result size: expected at most 1
>           at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.execute(GraphQueryExecution.java:83)

Any pointers on what I need to change in the query?

***Updates***

1. User class

   ```
   @NodeEntity
   public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   public Long getId() {
       return id;
   }

   @Index(unique = true)
   private String emailAddress;

   private String name;

   @Relationship(type = "INTERESTED_IN", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
   private Set<UserInterest> interests = new HashSet<>();

   public Set<UserInterest> getInterests() {
       return interests;
   }

   public void setInterests(Set<UserInterest> interests) {
       this.interests = interests;
   }

   @Relationship(type = "KNOWS", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
   private Set<RelatedUser> relatedUsers = new HashSet<>();

   public Set<RelatedUser> getRelatedUsers() {
       return relatedUsers;
   }

   public void setRelatedUsers(Set<RelatedUser> relatedUsers) {
       this.relatedUsers = relatedUsers;
   }

   ... additional getters/setters

   }
   ```

Comment: You aren't COLLECT-ing any of the results, is i1 and i2 guaranteed to only return at most 1 value? Note that multiple values for any of the variables will result in a query with multiple rows. You will need to decide how you want to aggregate the results so that there is only 1 result.

Comment: The first query is bringing back multiple rows but I don’t get the exception. I only get the exception when I extend the query to get the user connections.

Comment: Can you share the User class so that we can see what Spring is expecting?

Comment: User class added above.

Comment: It looks like not all the class properties are listed at the top of the class, does this snippet include all of the class properties?

Comment: I’ve excluded the imports and additional getters setters. The only properties the class has is id, name, emailAddress, interests and relatedUsers. Interests and relatedUsers are sets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183512/discussion-between-tezra-and-swordfish).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Spring-data-neo4j [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation), the proper method signature is

```
// <class> finedBy<property><flags>(<property type> value)
User findByEmailAddressIgnoreCase(String emailAddress)
```